# can one CursorAdapter be prepared for multiple columns? SQLite DataBase

Tags: java, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

Do I set up a dataset with multiple columns using the Cursor adapter? Each data set does not have a fixed value with different column numbers.

https://i.hizliresim.com/3Oa424.jpg

I want it that way.

https://i.hizliresim.com/P7obEQ.jpg

Activity.

```
    list = view.findViewById(R.id.malzemelist);
    String TarifDetay = "SELECT ID as _id, recipe_id,name,quantity,unit FROM malzemelist WHERE recipe_id=" + 1;
    adapter = new adapter_tarif(getActivity(), db.rawQuery(TarifDetay, null));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_malzeme_tek, viewGroup, false);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    malzemedetay = view.findViewById(R.id.malzemedetayitem);
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String quantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
    String unit = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("unit"));
    malzemedetay.setText(quantity + " " + unit + " " + name);
}
```